# Cakephp, how to saveAll 1200000 data form SQL server to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes)
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes)
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes)
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes)
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes)
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes)
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes)
```

Comment: Try splitting it into chunks of 10000 at a time or something, your error seems to say you ran out of memory - probably from loading too much data at once.

Comment: i can set the limit to 10000 but it will only save that much and i dont get  the whole data

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of what I meant

Comment: I would increase the memory to a 512 megabytes. Try: `ini_set(“memory_limit”,”512M”);`.

Comment: Is this an operation you need to do frequently? If not, and this is just a one-time import, I would definitely investigate a direct export/import option. You're not performing any significant data transformations. Hell, you could export to a CSV and import that into MySQL.

Comment: yes i need to do this frequently we get 10000 data every hour i could import that one time then i need to import new data every hour dose it make any sens

Comment: If you want to run it every hour you should run a shell script every hour with a cron job. The script would be literally be 2 lines and have no limitations.

Comment: yep thats what i was thinking i'll try both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CakePHP implementation of josh.trow's solution:

```
class DetailsController extends AppController
{
    var $uses = array('Detail','DataDetail');

    function import()
    {
        $max = $this->Detail->find('count');

        $offset = 0;
        $limit = 10000;

        do {
            $exportedData = $importableData = array();

            $exportedData = $this->Detail->find('all', array(
                'order' => 'Detail.id',
                'limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset
            ));

            foreach($exportedData as $k => $row) {

                $importableData[] = array('DataDetail'=>array(
                    'id' => $row['Detail']['ID'],
                    'name' => $row['Detail']['name']
                ));
            }

            $this->DataDetail->saveAll($importableData,array('validate'=>false));

            $offset += $limit;

        } while ($offset <= $max);

        $this->flash(__("The details have been imported.",true));
    }
}
```

Reduce the size of `$limit` as needed to accommodate your memory constraints. You'll probably also need to increase the `max_execution_time` configuration variable in php.ini, as cycling through 1.2M records will take awhile.

**NB**: I definitely don't recommend this solution unless you need to perform this operation frequently and without human intervention.

**NB2**: I should note as well that Cake lacks the capability (natively) to aggregate many rows in a single `INSERT`, so this solution will perform as many queries against your MySQL DB as there are rows in your MSSQL DB. Using Cake for this is entirely unnecessary, and my solution should be considered nothing more than a proof of concept.

Comment: Ahhh thank you sir someone who knows PHP and Cake finally arrived :)

Comment: 10000/hr is no small number, so I suppose this could work for him, assuming it runs fast enough (and I don't see why it wouldn't)

Comment: Did I miss where the OP indicated this was more than a one-time import? Also, it will be slow because the solution introduces PHP into the equation, which is slow, then adds the entire CakePHP stack without anything of it except a tiny sliver of its ORM.

Comment: i get data but with lots of error here is one of them its from SQL server SQL Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The ranking function "row_number" must have an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: MSSQL must not like offset/limit parameters without an order parameter. I've updated my code sample.

Comment: its seems its working i see data coming thank you . is there any way we could do like lets see if the data is new import else false thanks

Comment: Last time I answer someone with no rep on SO!

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this by saying I don't know PHP, so this is DEFINITELY pseudocode:

```
max = countTotalRows(sourceDB)  // COUNT ONLY, DO NOT GET ACTUAL DATA
base = 0;
step = 10000;
do {
  getRows();                    // now you get data - (step) rows of it per loop
  storeRows();                  // and store it
  base += step;
} while ( base <= max )
```

EDIT:
Shamelessly borrowed from http://www.devdaily.com/php/php-cakephp-database-sql-query-select

`$results = $this->Order->query("select * from (your table name) LIMIT (the base), (the step)");`

Again, I don't know Cake or PHP so you will have to do the syntax, etc but this may help you start.

Comment: well how can i do this cake way its diffrent

Comment: I do what I can with the knowledge I have. I know I appreciate anything so that's what I try to give people.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things you are just importing one table into another with no change of data/structure. Just take a SQL/CSV dump from the Detail table and import it into the other database, then just rename it DataDetail.

If DataDetail already exists, just dump the data with insert ignore, you can do this in phpmyadmin and save it as a file.

Comment: In that case you are giving yourself a massive unnecessary headache and lots of extra load by doing it inside CakePHP. At the very least do it **without** CakePHP.